# Thread Safe Efficient way to implement singleton pattern in Java?

Tags: java, singleton, thread-safety, synchronized

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Efficient way to implement singleton pattern in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/efficient-way-to-implement-singleton-pattern-in-java)

I was reading this [Best Singleton Implementation In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/best-singleton-implementation-in-java), but its not thread safe.

As per wiki :

> `if(singleton==null)  { 
>   synchronized(Singleton.class) { //
>   this is needed if two threads are
>   waiting at the monitor at the // time
>   when singleton was getting
>   instantiated  if(singleton==null) 
>   singleton= new Singleton();  }
>
>   }`

But Find Bugs utility gives two errors in this : 
1. Double null check. 
2. Incorrect lazy initialization of static field.

What is the best way,

Is it Correct :

> ```
> synchronized (Singleton.class) {
> if (singleton== null) {
> singleton= new Singleton();
> }
> }
> ```

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question above; see that question for details. But I'm not sure that question has these useful links, so: [About double-checked locking in Java](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl.html) which links to [these](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp02244.html) [two](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp03304/) updates for Java 5. See also [Wikipedia's article on double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking). But for the actual answer to your question, see the question linked above.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The most efficient/simplest way to make a lazy loading Singleton is just

```
enum Singleton {
   INSTANCE
}
```

Note: there is no need for locking as class loading is thread safe. The class is final by default and the constructor cannot be called via reflection. The INSTANCE will not be created until the INSTANCE, or the class is used.  If you are worried the class might be accidentally used you can wrap the singleton in an inner class.

```
final class Singleton {
    private Singleton() { }
    static class SingletonHolder {
        static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    }
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

IMHO, you have to be pretty paranoid to consider this a better solution.

Comment: In your second code u are not using `enum` but you are using `class` so i am confused how to take it. I want to make a enum to initialize a class once and call that object every next time.How can i do that.Can you please give an example in detail

Comment: @Manish In that case, use an `enum` like I do in the first example.

Comment: yah that is ok but how can I initialize a class just once and use that instance every next time using `enum`. that is my confusion.every where i just see `enum Singleton {
   INSTANCE
}` this much but not how to call and initialize object

Comment: You can use `Singleton.INSTANCE` anywhere in your code.  The code, which is called once in a thread safe way, to initialise this instance will be in your constructor for the `enum`

Comment: @PeterLawrey didnt you forget about private constructor Singleton() in you code snippet?

Comment: @MarianPaździoch indeed. Needs to be `final` as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The first code sample in the accepted answer for [Efficient way to implement singleton pattern in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/best-singleton-implementation-in-java) *is* thread safe. The creation of the `INSTANCE` is performed by the class loader the first time the class is loaded; it's performed exactly once, and in a thread-safe way:

```
public final class Foo {

    private static final Foo INSTANCE = new Foo();

    private Foo() {
        if (INSTANCE != null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Already instantiated");
        }
    }

    public static Foo getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

(copied from [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/efficient-way-to-implement-singleton-pattern-in-java/73763#73763))

The 2nd code sample in the question is correct and thread-safe, but it causes synchronization on each call to `getInstance()`, which affects performance.

Comment: Isn't protecting the private constructor is fairly paranoid. I assume its to avoid creating another instance using reflection, or is it to stop inner classes calling the constructor?

Comment: I was discussing an answer from a previous question, so I copied the code as-is. Personally I would omit the `if (INSTANCE != null)` check as well.

Comment: and therefor the exception I assume. ;)

Comment: Hi Eli, from your answer i understand there will be a single copy of the Foo object. But suppose two threads call the getInstance() function at the same time. then i believe there will be a race condition. how to avoid that.hence we need to avoid that. Please have a look at [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930633/java-synchronize-in-singleton-pattern[/link] to get the final answer...

Answer (score 3):

A lot has been written about this issue. Yes, the simple double-check-locking pattern is not safe. But you can make it safe by declaring the static instance as volatile. The new Java Memory Model specification adds some code-reordering restrictions for compilers when dealing with volatile, therefore the original risks are gone.

Anyway, I rarely really need this kind of lazyness when creating the instance, so I usually simply create it statically at class-loading time:

```
private static MyClass instance = new MyClass();
```

This is short and clear. As an alternative, if you really want to make it lazy, you can take advantage of the class loading characteristics and do this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static class MyClassInit {
        public static final MyClass instance = new MyClass();
    }

    public static MyClass getInstance() {
        return MyClassInit.instance; 
    }
...
}
```

The nested class will not be loaded until the first time you call getInstance().